# How to remove the '\x0' from a python string?

Tags: python, string, unicode, binary, xor

```
def sxor(s1,s2):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for a,b in  zip (s1,s2))

text = sxor('a','a')
text
```

output is

```
\x00
```

Tried a lot of previously answered methods but none works to remove '\x0' only as only '0' is the required answer.

Here's one more example :

```
def sxor(s1,s2):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for a,b in  zip (s1,s2))

text = sxor('1','2')
```

ouput

```
\x03
```

Things i have tried :

```
def sxor(s1,s2):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for a,b in  zip (s1,s2))

text = sxor('1','1')
text.rstrip('\x0')
```

error shown :

```
  File "<ipython-input-26-d4905edd1961>", line 6
    text.rstrip('\x0')
               ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-2: truncated \xXX escape
```

And if i write it like '\x00', then it also removes the required part and also doesn't work for any other case. I have also tried using replace function.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Replace `chr` to `str`

Comment: Note that `\x00` is single character: `print(len("\x00"))` output is `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `chr` to `str`.

1. [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) makes a single character string from `int` value as ascii code. So `chr(0)` means ascii `0` character, which is represented `'\x00'`.
2. What you want is [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str). It makes string from given value(`int` in this case). `str(0)` is `'0'`.

examples:

```py
print('\x00' == chr(0))
print('\x01' == chr(1))
print('0' == str(0))
print('1' == str(1))
```

output:

```py
True
True
True
True
```